# C# and Oracle carriage return

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to get a carriage return to happen with C# when inserting into an oracle database but I can't seem to get it correct.

I know its CHR(13) but when I run the replace on the string it replaces a specific character that i am using to mark a carriage return but when the insert happens it comes in with "CHR(13)" instead of a carriage return.

This is what I am using:

```
txt = txt.Replace("|", "' ||CHAR(13)|| '");
```

I have also tried setting a variable and giving it the calue of char(13) but same result.

```
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, txt) VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + record.first_name + "', '" + record.last_name + "', '" + txt + "')";
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO people (cust_sid, first_name, last_name, notes) VALUES ('10', 'steve', 'man','thisistext ||CHR(13)|| 07, more:more,  ||CHR(13)')
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some more code and preferably the final query before you execute it? And shouldn't it be `CHR(13)` instead of `CHAR(13)`?

Comment: Are you building a dynamic query? If `txt` is passed as a parameter, all you need to do is `txt.Replace("|", "\r")`.

Comment: Yeah it is CHR(13) i tried that also but CHAR(13) came up on a different post here so thought i'd give it a go also.

@Luaan txt is passed as a string to a class that handles the insert statement

Comment: Make an output of the entire SQL statement. You should prefer bind variables.

Comment: Please use bind variables. You won't have problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the last '|' at the end of `txt`.  It's definitely possible to triage this and do what you're trying to do, but as others have said in the comments, please don't.

Consider, what if your variable `txt` contains the following:

```
He'll do just fine
```

How are you going to handle the `'` character, and more importantly do you really want to?

Bind variables are like bacon -- they make everything better:

```
// OracleConnection conn;

int id = 1;
string txt = "this is text|more:more, |";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
    "insert into people (id, first_name, last_name, txt) values " +
    "(:ID, :FIRST, :LAST, :TXT)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", id);
cmd.Parameters.Add("FIRST", "steve");
cmd.Parameters.Add("LAST", "man");
cmd.Parameters.Add("TXT", txt.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you were inserting more than a single record, you'd want to do this a little differently (declare parameters once, execute multiple times with different values), but the same basic concepts would apply.